# How do i extract a list of all cells that contain a text string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say I have this list:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stack East | 500 |
| 2 | Stack West | 600 |
| 3 | Whack One | 700 |
| 4 | Track Yellow | 500 |
| 5 | Stack North | 500 |
| 6 | Stack North | 700 |

Stack North is Cell A; 500 is cell B.

I want a new tab which only shows e.g. the cells that contain the word "stack". And then I want the values from column B e.g. next to the right "Stack". This is for a list of debitors from the same group, but different locations and i want to summarize the extract from an accounting software to an excel sheet to send it out.

I tried index+match but it does not really work as it is prob unsure which value to put into the cell and i cant drag it down. If i copy the list and use find+replace, it is not able to automatically update in the future when i just copy in a new extract from next month or so.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have.  The FILTER() function in Office 365 does this easily: `=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:B6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("stack",Sheet1!A1:A6)))`

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2016 and more recent, you can use PowerQuery. In the table do « insert/table ». This will declare the array as a table, which makes it easily available from PowerQuery (tables have half of the lines colored).

Then « Data/from a table ». You will enter the PowerQuery editor. With a dropdown menu on a column, you can create a filter. When validated, the filter is memorized and shown at the right panel. The preview is actualized.

Now, click at the left top icon « close and load ». The request output is added in a new tab. If you change the source data, go to the result tab, right-click « actualize » and the memorized query is computed again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no version restrictions as per your tags, you can use the `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(myTab,LEFT(myTab[A],5)="Stack")
```

[image]